# rhive.connect() issue

Tags: r

I was trying to connect to hive using `RHive` but I'm getting a connection refused error.

```
library(RHive)
Loading required package: rJava
Loading required package: Rserve
This is RHive 0.0-7. For overview type â?RHiveâ.
HIVE_HOME=/home/surya/hive-0.8.1
call rhive.init() because HIVE_HOME is set.
> rhive.connect()
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  :
  org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
NULL
```

Comment: if you have solved this problem please post your ans. thanks

Answer (score 1):

open your terminal and follow below steps.

1. first start your hadoop hdfs

   cd /usr/local/hadoop && /bin/start-all.sh
2. start your hive serve

   cd /usr/local/hive/  && bin/hive --service hiveserver

it will start process and don't close your terminal

Now open your R/Rstudio and run below statements

```
library(Rserve) #loading R server package
Rserve(args=”—no-save”)
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME=”/usr/local/hadoop”)
Sys.setenv(HIVE_HOME=”/usr/local/hive”)
library(RHive)
rhive.connect()
rhive.env()
rhive.init()
x=1:10
y=x**2
xy=data.frame(x,y)
rhive.write.tables(xy)
rhive.list.tables()
```

now you can see a table of xy on hive

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue and was able to resolve this issue by *reconfiguring the Java for R by simple command in Linux CentOS 6.2*:

`$R CMD javareconf`