# Connection Error to connect Rhive to R

Tags: r, hive

I get the following connection error when trying to connect `Rhive` to `R`:

```
> rhive.connect(host = "192.168.1.138", port = 9000,defaultFS = "hdfs://localhost:9000")
Warning: 
    +----------------------------------------------------------+
    + / hiveServer2 argument has not been provided correctly.  +
    + / RHive will use a default value: hiveServer2=TRUE.      +
    +----------------------------------------------------------+

16/08/14 13:36:03 INFO jdbc.Utils: Supplied authorities: 192.168.1.138:9000
16/08/14 13:36:03 INFO jdbc.Utils: Resolved authority: 192.168.1.138:9000
16/08/14 13:36:03 INFO jdbc.HiveConnection: Transport Used for JDBC connection: null


Exception in thread "Thread-16" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://192.168.1.138:9000/default: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

    at com.nexr.rhive.hive.HiveJdbcClient$HiveJdbcConnector.connect(HiveJdbcClient.java:337)
    at com.nexr.rhive.hive.HiveJdbcClient$HiveJdbcConnector.run(HiveJdbcClient.java:322)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://192.168.1.138:9000/default: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:208)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:154)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at com.nexr.rhive.hive.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:51)
    at com.nexr.rhive.hive.HiveJdbcClient$HiveJdbcConnector.connect(HiveJdbcClient.java:330)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:226)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:266)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:183)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSenter code hereocket.open(TSocket.java:221)
    ... 10 more
Errorjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected to hiveserver`enter code here`
```

Comment: Maybe these steps could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/17463996/2026277

Comment: sorry but it did not worked @JaimeCr